# Where can I read about the theory behind GLMs in their most general form?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, references, mathematical-statistics

I was following along with the MIT Opencourseware "Statistics for Applications" and their analysis of GLMs only covers discussion of GLMs whose dependent variable $y$ is distributed according to a distribution in the *canonical* exponential family (i.e. of the form below):
$$
P(y\ |\ \theta) = h(y)\exp(\theta^Ty - A(\theta))
$$
If this is the case, then one can easily determine that $\mu = \mathbb{E}[Y] = A'(\theta)$, and since $\mu$ is related to the linear predictor via the link function $g$, we have
$$
X^T\beta = g(A'(\theta)),\qquad \theta = (g\circ A')^{-1}(X^T\beta)
$$

However, I'm curious about the more general case where the distribution belongs to the **overdispersed exponential family**:
$$
P(\mathbf y\ |\ \theta,\tau) = h(y,\tau)\exp\left(\frac{\mathbf b(\mathbf \theta)^T\mathbf{T}(\mathbf y) - A(\theta)}{d(\tau)}\right)
$$

Using the identity $\mathbb{E}[\nabla_\theta\ell] = 0$ where $\ell$ is the log-likelihood function I was able to arrive at
$$
[D_\theta \mathbf b]^T\mathbb{E}[\mathbf T(\mathbf y)] = \nabla_\theta A
$$
but there are two problems with this. For one, the dimension of $\mathbf b$ might not equal the dimension of $\theta$, and even if it did this would not guarantee the matrix $D_\theta\mathbf b$ (the Jacobian of $\mathbf b$) is invertible. Second, even if it were invertible, we would only arrive at
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf T(\mathbf y)] = ([D_\theta \mathbf b]^T)^{-1}\nabla_\theta A
$$
which doesn't give us any direct correspondence between the parameter $\theta$ and the linear predictor $\mathbf X^T\beta$, since the link function links $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf y]$ to $\mathbf X^T\beta$, not $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf T(\mathbf y)]$.

So, how are GLMs of this form implemented? Where can I go to read more about how this works?

Comment: I think your notation might be a bit off, but the form you have above is close to the Aitkin definition of the exponential family and can be used to generalize to working with overdispersion. McCullagh and Nelder's book Generalized Linear Models includes discussions about doing so.

Comment: You can find answers in this dups:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209531/is-there-a-glm-bible,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67626/understanding-of-glm